# How to iterate a JSON data in HTML in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a JSON response 'result' from JS like below:

```
[{"Name":"Alexy Portal",
"Description":"New Record <span style="background-color:#FFFF00;">New</span>",
"Title":"New Record <span style="background-color:#FFFF00;">New</span>"}]
```

I need to put it in table format. I tried to use

```
<template for:each={result} for:item="res">
   <li key={res.Title}>
      <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={res.Title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
   </li>
</template>
```

to get the Data in HTML so that i can put it in table format. but its not working. Could anyone please suggest any solution? It will be really helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for formatting your code - that is helpful. But since it was multiple lines of code, I edited your question in order to format the code as block rather than inline code - just to help see it better. When I did, I discovered what appears to be a stray `</div>`. Is that a typo or a copy/paste error? If not, that could cause an issue.

Comment: it was a typo, made changes

Comment: Also, please edit your question to elaborate on what you mean by "not working." Are you getting an error? (If so, include *exact* error text.) Is it giving unexpected results? Or expected results at an unexpected time? Does it seem to just not do anything? Please give more information.

Answer (score 2):

**For LWC template for:each you MUST specify element with "key" atribute at Top level .**
So this code should work.

```
<template for:each={result} for:item="res">
  <div key={res.Title}>
     <li key={res.Title}>
        <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={res.Title}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
     </li>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Also please ensure that data in JS saved as Array Not as String or Object**